# How to extract lines from 2nd column in one file that can be found in the other file?

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files like this:

```
head 1000G.EUR.7.bim
7   rs7456436   0.0085998121    44935   T   C
7   rs7384563   0.0099808474    45653   C   T
7   rs6583338   0.011117913 46239   G   A
7   rs62429403  0.03835409  53998   C   A
7   rs4281072   0.039011123 54183   T   C
7   rs6965835   0.051294015 57660   C   T
7   rs12670102  0.060656098 60392   T   C
7   rs62429414  0.061278166 60728   A   G

head c7.txt
SNP A1 A2 Z
rs62429403 C A -0.317767
rs62429404 C G -0.0968181
rs73260517 C G 0.362803
rs56339393 C T 0.361902
rs6950543 C G -0.325175
rs62429407 G A 0.357001
rs62429414 A G 1.11945
```

I want to find lines in file c7.txt that have matching rs### in the 1000G.EUR.7.bim. For example the solution for this sample would be:

```
SNP A1 A2 Z
rs62429403 C A -0.317767
rs62429414 A G 1.11945
```

I tried doing this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0; if(NR==1) print $0} ($1 in a) {print a[$1]}' 1000G.EUR.7.bim c7.txt > output.txt
```

But I am getting lines from 1000G.EUR.7.bim matching to ct.txt instead of lines from c7.txt matching 1000G.EUR.7.bim based on the rs### column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]; next} $1 in a' 1000G.EUR.7.bim c7.txt > output.txt
```

Save the second field of `1000G.EUR.7.bim` in array `a` and print the line of `c7.txt` if the `rsXXX` value is present in the array.

Comment: sorry one more thing I am missing the header in this result file, which should be this: "SNP A1 A2 Z" how do I include that as well?

Comment: I guess I can do this, considering I am doing this on multiple files:  for txt in output*.txt; do (echo "SNP A1 A2 Z"; cat $txt) > tmp; mv tmp $txt; done

Comment: If the header is the first line of the second file, change `$1 in a` to `FNR==1 || $1 in a`. Or if you want to add it yourself, you could use something like `FNR==1{print "SNP A1 A2 Z"}`.